# Divide a rectangle into parts

Tags: diagrams

Several months ago I wrote a code to divide a circle into parts.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\mysegments{15}
\def\myradius{2}
\draw[fill=purple!40] (0,0) -- (0:2) arc[start angle=0, end angle=216,radius=2cm];
\foreach \x in {1,...,\mysegments} {
    \draw (0,0) --++ (360/\mysegments*\x:\myradius) arc (360/\mysegments*\x:360/\mysegments*     
(\x+1):\myradius);
   % \draw (360/\mysegments*\x:\myradius) node {\tiny\textbullet};
   % \node at (360/\mysegments*\x-180/\mysegments:\myradius/1.5) {\x};
  }
 \draw (0,0) node {\tiny\textbullet};
 \draw[color=black,line width=1pt] (0,0) circle (2cm);
 \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{document}
```

Now I want to do something similar with a rectangle. I want to give some numbers (say `k` and `m`) to divide the rectangle horizontally and vertically into parts.

Do you have an idea?

Comment: If you don't want to program, the ProfCollege package offers a lot of commands like \Fraction[Rectangle,Multiple=3,Reponse]{9/12}

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you have in mind? Here is a macro `\fracrect{k}{m}` that divides a rectangle into `m` pieces and fills `k` of them. There is an optional argument to include `tikz` options such as `rotate`, `xscale`, `yscale`, `thick`, etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}

\newcommand{\fracrect}[3][]{\tikz[baseline, #1]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#2}{\draw[fill=purple!40] ({(\n-1)/#3},0) rectangle (\n/#3,1);}
    \foreach \n in {#2,...,#3} {\draw ({(\n-1)/#3},0) rectangle (\n/#3,1);}}}

\begin{document}
\fracrect[xscale=4]{3}{4}\qquad
\fracrect[yscale=3, rotate=90]{9}{15}
\end{document}
```